# Button height with display flex is not uniform in Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have a `button` encapsulated under the `div` with the following structure:

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="parent-container">
      <div class="child child-1 col-xs-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Customize Feed</button>
      </div>
      <div class="child child-2 col-xs-6">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Really Really Really Really Really Really Long CTA text</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .parent-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    .child-1 {
      order: 2;
    }

    .child-2 {
      order: 1;
    }

    .child button {
      height: 100%;
      white-space: normal;
    }

    .child button {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

The two buttons (both with long text and shorter text), should occupy the same height irrespective of their content's length. It works well across all the browsers **except** for Safari in macOS.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qe4kmd05/)

**Issue Screenshot** *(from the demo)*:

[image: *The buttons improper height*]

Comment: Thanks. Hope other user answer your question. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes to your CSS and got it working.

The parent element of the `button` needs to have flexbox in order for the button to become *flexible*.

```css
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.child-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  order: 2;
}

.child-2 {
  order: 1;
}

.child button {
  flex: 1;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="child child-1 col-xs-6">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Customize Feed</button>
  </div>
  <div class="child child-2 col-xs-6">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Really Really Really Really Really Really Long CTA text</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffmiller/95nejfps/)

Comment: although it's working as per desired, but if the `button` is made to display in a single line (for mobile devices), it doesn't takes the same height. Any guess why?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way for the elements to have an equal height is if they're on the same row. In order to match the heights when they're on separate lines, you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah that is the only way. Thanks!